# RegEx to match tokens and keep delimiter

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using this RegEx (vb.net) to match all tokens of a string and to keep the delimiters (separate capturing groups):

`([^~\+\:]*)([~\+\:])`

`Text1+Text2::Text4::Text6~Text1+Text2:Text3+Text4~`

Output:

`Text1  +
 Text2  :
        :
 Text4  :
        :
 Text6  ~
 Text1  +
 Text2  :
 Text3  +
 Text4  ~`

How can I achieve the same with `?` as escape delimiter (odd number of `?`)?

`Text1+Text2?:Text3~`

should result in

`Text1        +
Text2?:Text3  ~`

Thanks for your help

Comment: What would `Text1+Text2??:Text3~` return? My guess: `Text1  +`, `Text2?  :`, and `Text3  ~`...

Comment: [`(.*?)((?<![?])[~\+\:])`](http://regex101.com/r/bK8tH5/1)?

Comment: Thanks. But that does not work for multiple `?` and the `(.*?)` is a bit of a performance killer.

Comment: That's why I asked what you want to do with multiple `?`'s...I'm not really sure what the goal there is. The `.*?` probably is more efficient than some of the other options (but I can ponder it) due to the fact that you can't just do a simple match of a character class..since it's varying.

Comment: Here's something more efficient (roughly half the steps per match), still has the same `??` problem..if you answer my first comment I can finish my expression and post an answer/description: [`((?:[^~+:]|(?<=\?))*)(.)`](http://regex101.com/r/bK8tH5/2)

Comment: Your assumption in the first comment is correct. Two `??` would esacpe the second `?` but not any following delimiter. Only an odd number of preceding `?` will escape the delimiter. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
((?:\?.|[^~+:])*)([~+:])
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bK8tH5/3)

---

This will not necessarily escape a `?a` into `a` or `??` into `?`, so you will need to do some post-processing without regex.  However, a `?` will effectively escape the next character.  So: `?:` will not be a delimiter, `??:` will be a delimiter, `???:` will not be a delimiter.

---

Explanation:

```
(           (?# start capture group for text)
  (?:       (?# start non-capture group for repeating alternation)
    \?.     (?# match ? literally followed by any character -- escaping)
   |        (?# OR)
    [^~+:]  (?# match any non-delimiter characters ~, +, and :)
  )*        (?# repeat non-capture group 0+ time)
)           (?# end capture group)
(           (?# start capture group for delimiter)
  [~+:]     (?# match any delimiter character ~, +, and :)
)           (?# end capture group)
```

Comment: This should be fully tested..let me know if something is wrong, or if you have any questions :)